# Intersection of a line with a line segment in C++

Tags: c++, geometry, line, computational-geometry, intersection

The following is `C++` code taken from [CP3](http://cpbook.net/#CP3details), which calculates the point of intersection between the line that passes through a and b, and the line **segment** defined by p and q, assuming the intersection exists. Can someone explain what it is doing and why it works (geometrically)?

```
// line segment p-q intersect with line A-B.
point lineIntersectSeg(point p, point q, point A, point B) {
  double a = B.y - A.y;
  double b = A.x - B.x;
  double c = B.x * A.y - A.x * B.y;
  double u = fabs(a * p.x + b * p.y + c);
  double v = fabs(a * q.x + b * q.y + c);
  return point((p.x * v + q.x * u) / (u+v), (p.y * v + q.y * u) / (u+v));
}
```

Note that this solution seems to be different to that explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565282/1505018) or in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Intersection%20of%20two%20lines) since this solution makes use of the absolute value function.

I've expanded the expressions that result for the point of intersection (x, y):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)

Comment: Seems like it is essentially the same method as [the formula in Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Intersection%20of%20two%20lines), though written slightly differently.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point would be to understand what to do to find line intersection yourself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection

- Line Segment: *y = ax + c*
- Line: *y = bx + d*
- Intersection [image] and [image]

Now we'll just need to get *a* and *c* in terms of `p` and `q` and *b* and *d* in terms of `A` and `B`.

We know both of our slopes:

- `a = (p.y - q.y) / (p.x - q.x)`
- `b = (A.y - B.y) / (A.x - B.x)`

I tend to use the [Point-Slope Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Point.E2.80.93slope_form) to find the y-intercept:

- *y -*`p.y`*= a(x -*`p.x`*)* which will simplify to *y = ax -* `(p.x * q.y - p.y * q.x) / (p.x - q.x)`
- *y -*`A.y`*= a(x -*`B.x`*)* which will simplify to *y = ax -* `(A.x * B.y - A.y * B.x) / (A.x - B.x)`

So if you'll permit me to mix our variables into math notation so simplification is simpler, our final equation for our intersection components is:

- [image]
- [image]

Once the fractions in the numerators and denominators have been combined into a single fraction, the denominator for both is seen to be `(A.x - B.x)(p.x - q.x)` So both denominators can be removed yielding:

- [image]
- [image]

Comment: You don't explain the `fabs` in the supplied equation.  I suspect it's something clever to do with avoiding division-by-zero errors.  Your simple formula will blow up if (for example) Ax=Bx.

Comment: This is correct as long as none of the lines are vertical. This doesn't explain the use of `fabs`.

Comment: @hallaplay835 That's a good call, note that the original equation doesn't handle them either. It will return a valid number for non-intersecting lines: http://ideone.com/t1hzRD

Comment: The original code works **as long as the intersection exists**. One of the lines can be vertical, though.

Comment: @hallaplay835 Wait this is with a line segment as well, so how would we check if an intersection existed?

Comment: Doing vector cross-product. If `ab x ap` has different sign as `ab x aq`, then one of the points `p`, `q` lies on one side of the line, and the other point on the other side.